# symmetricds version 3.10.4 opensource tool installation and setup

Tags: oracle, postgresql, symmetricds

Is there any document covering the complete installation, setup and demo for symmetricds version 3.10.4 opensource version? I am able to find the demo for Pro version.

I am trying for PostgreSQL and Oracle Database from windows.

Comment: What's wrong with the [User guide](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_installation)?

Answer (score 1):

as a_horse_with_no_name has mentioned the user guide https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_installation should be used. you'll need to spend some time configuring postgreSql and oracle DBs as the user guide would be lot longer having all combinations of supported database types